# Serial interface initialisation with arduino and C

Tags: c, macos, serial-port, arduino

I want to "talk" with my arduino using C on my mac. I first used the code in the link given on the arduino official website: http://todbot.com/blog/2006/12/06/arduino-serial-c-code-to-talk-to-arduino/

Using the "blink" example it simply doesn't work, I know that newer arduinos reset when the serial port is open but even with adding a delay (up to 4s) it simply blinks once whatever character I send.

I also tried to change the code by disabling HUPCL (should prevent the reset) in the termios flags but it doesn't change anything.

The *funny* thing is that it is working if I load the serial monitor of the Arduino official app in the background. The command screen is also fully functional. So I guess it has something to do with the initialisation of the serial communication. I then tried to get the flags (l, i, o and c) used by the monitor using **stty -a** and used them in my C program... without luck!

Thanks for any help!

PS: this is a chinese clone bought on ebay... maybe it can be relevant

EDIT: I tried to use python to do the same thing with pyserial and it does the same: works only if the arduino app's serial monitor is running at the same time

Comment: There is no such thing as a "clone" of an arduino - the hardware is open source, anyone can build and distribute it.

Comment: Also, run this command in the terminal when the arduino is plugged in: `ls /dev/ |grep tty.usbserial`

Comment: I know that the hardware is open source but I've seen forum posts where people had troubles with a cheap arduino...
The command gets me this 'tty.usbserial-A5006HGR'

Comment: The arduino is connecting to the computer and opening a successful connection then... you should be able to write bytes to that file and have them sent to the arduino.

Comment: I know, like I wrote it is working using the serial monitor but not if I use C or python, which is what I want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I think I found it.

I was able to try an arduino Uno, and the result was the same. I then realised that for some obscure reason my arduino is reseting at **each** communication over the serial port, and not only at the first connection. As the result is the same under windows I guess it has something to do with my laptop (MBP 15", early 2011, 10.7.4).

I then search a bit and found that there is actually a way to disable DTR (the signal that makes the board to reset) either with C or Python.

```
import serial, time

#open the serial port
s = serial.Serial(port='/dev/tty.usbserial-A5006HGR', baudrate=9600)

#disable DTR
s.setDTR(level=False)

#wait for 2 seconds
time.sleep(2)

#send the data
s.write("7")
```

In C you need to to load the parameters from the serial port, disable DTR and then update the parameters, this is done using `ioctl` (from http://www.easysw.com/~mike/serial/serial.html#5_1_2)

```
//load status
int status;
ioctl(fd, TIOCMGET, &status);

//disable DTR
status &= ~TIOCM_DTR;

//update the status
ioctl(fd, TIOCMSET, &status);
```

This can be placed in the code after the port has been opened. However the board will still reboot at the first connection, the first delay is then still necessary.

I hope this will help people in the same (unusual) situation.

Comment: Does this remove the delay when using the [arduino-serial](http://todbot.com/blog/2006/12/06/arduino-serial-c-code-to-talk-to-arduino/) command? For example, my project responds immediately when I call "./arduino-serial -b 9600 -p /dev/tty.usbmodemfa131 -d 2000 -s 1" or when I call w/o the delay AND the arduino serial monitor is open...

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I found that for Python(in my case 2.7.3) in Linux you must do like this:

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
ser.dsrdtr=False
ser.setDTR(level=False)
```

There will be no Reset

Answer (score 0):

I have not found that method to be too reliable for opening serial ports on the mac. I would suggest using ioctl, as it is much more robust and offers many advantages, mainly the use of any arbitrary baud rate.

```
#import <IOKit/serial/ioss.h>
#import <sys/ioctl.h>

- (int)serialInit:(const char*)path baud:(int)baud;
{
    struct termios options;

    // open the serial like POSIX C
    int serialFileDescriptor = open(path, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);

    // block non-root users from using this port
    ioctl(serialFileDescriptor, TIOCEXCL);

    // clear the O_NONBLOCK flag, so that read() will
    //   block and wait for data.
    fcntl(serialFileDescriptor, F_SETFL, 0);

    // grab the options for the serial port
    tcgetattr(serialFileDescriptor, &options);

    // setting raw-mode allows the use of tcsetattr() and ioctl()
    cfmakeraw(&options);

    // specify any arbitrary baud rate
    ioctl(serialFileDescriptor, IOSSIOSPEED, &baud);

    return serialFileDescriptor;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried your code, it hangs if I keep the 'fcntl' line. If I remove it, then it doesn't change anything and behaves like before: it blinks only once.

Also I tried to do it on windows using python (the very simple script given on the arduino website) and it just does the same thing. I guess it has something to do with the board and my computer, I will try to get another one to see if I'm luckier.